# Logistic regression in R when outcome is proportion data with more than two categories?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Let's say I have demographic data on various classes and the proportion of students in the class who are black, white, etc. I'm trying to create a regression to determine features of the class that are predictive of the proportion of each group within the class. I sensed that there may be some adaptation of a multinomial logistic regression that would work, but I cannot figure out how that would be.

Example data:

```
dfexample <- data.frame(
     subject = c('English', 'English', 'Math', 'Science'),
     enrollment = c(100,200,50,70),
     white = c(0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7),
     black = c(0.25,0.20, 0.10, 0.25),
     hispanic = c(0.25, 0.30, 0.30, 0.05),
     classid = c('1a','3f','4d','5a')
)

dfexample
  subject enrollment white black hispanic classid
1 English        100   0.5  0.25     0.25      1a
2 English        200   0.5  0.20     0.30      3f
3    Math         50   0.6  0.10     0.30      4d
4 Science         70   0.7  0.25     0.05      5a
```

In this dummy scenario I'd hope to create a model for the proportion of students of various race/ethnicity based on the subject and size of the class.

I thought of using logistic regression to predict fractions, but that seems to work only when the outcome is binary (e.g, True or False).

If not able to do this, the other alternative I was thinking was to do multiple logistic regressions (white vs nonwhite; black vs nonblack; hispanic vs nonhispanic). However this approach seemed lacking, and would this leave me open to multiple testing error?

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for multinomial regression. You could check out [this link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) for a walkthrough example.

Comment: Technically this would be a multi hypergeometric distribution. Multinational distribution (fit via multinomial regression) converges to hypergeometric for large populations, but I'm not sure if the nature of your data would justify that

Comment: @astrofunkswag: What's a "multinational distribution"? I tried Googling it but could find only books about international trade logistics and tax arrangements.

Comment: Looks like you need a fractional multinomial model. Not sure if R can do this or not. https://github.com/f1kidd/fmlogit

Answer (score 1):

Using [Caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html) library you can easily perform this task.

First, declare the imports and define your dataset.

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

dfexample <- data.frame(
       subject = c('English', 'English', 'Math', 'Science'),
       enrollment = c(100,200,50,70),
       white = c(0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7),
       black = c(0.25,0.20, 0.10, 0.25),
       hispanic = c(0.25, 0.30, 0.30, 0.05),
       classid = c('1a','3f','4d','5a')
   );
# replicating data frame rows to make our example works    
dfexample = dfexample[rep(seq_len(nrow(dfexample)), each = 20), ]
```

Then, determine the train and test set:

```
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(dfexample$classid, p = .6, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)
dataTrain <- dfexample[ trainIndex,]
dataTest  <- dfexample[-trainIndex,]
```

After that, run your model. 
If you need to test other models, take a look at this [link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) and check the model methods available. Then, change the method property as in the code below.

```
modelFit <- train(classid ~ subject + enrollment + white + black + hispanic, data = dataTrain, 
                  method = "LogitBoost",  
                  #method = "gbm",  
                  verbose = FALSE
)

print(modelFit)
```

Finally, generate the confusion matrix and analyze the predictions:

```
predictions <- predict(modelFit, newdata = dataTest)

cm = confusionMatrix(predictions, dataTest$classid)

print(cm)
```

I hope it helps you.